# JS DOM add new rows: I want to put the 2 buttons in line with values from inputs and also make them functional

Tags: javascript, selector, getelementbyid

I want to put the 2 buttons in line with values from inputs and also make them functional. My code:

```js
function addEntry() {
  document.getElementById('newEntry').style.display = "block";
  var name = document.querySelector('.name').value;
  var phone = document.querySelector('.phone').value;
  var btn1 = document.createElement('Button');
  var x = document.createTextNode("Modify");
  btn1.appendChild(x);
  document.body.appendChild(btn1);
  var btn2 = document.createElement('Button');
  var y = document.createTextNode("Delete");
  btn2.appendChild(y);
  document.body.appendChild(btn2);
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell1.innerHTML = name;
  cell2.innerHTML = phone;
  cell3.innerHTML = x;
  cell4.innerHTML = y;

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: bisque;
}

#header {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

#addnew {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(151, 64, 163);
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#entry {
  line-height: 50px;
}

span {
  margin: 5px;
}

#add {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: rgb(26, 126, 39);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.inputstyle {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#newEntry {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(151, 64, 163);
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
}

#myTable {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

td {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="header"><b>Phone Book</b></div>
  <div id="addnew">
    <div id="entry">
      <span>Name:</span><span><input class="inputstyle name" type="text" placeholder="Insert name..."/></span><span>PhoneNo:</span><span><input class="inputstyle phone" type="number" placeholder="Insert phone number..."/></span><br>
      <button id="add" type="button" value="Add new entry" onclick="addEntry();">Add Contact</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="newEntry">
    <table id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Link:** [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0w835xL1/16/)

Comment: Please put your code in the post itself

Comment: And please state your question, in detail, in the post as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) once, and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You are appending the buttons to the document body. You don't want to put them there. You need to append the buttons to one of the table cells instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the buttons to the document body. You don't want to put them there. You need to append the buttons to the table cells instead.

```
cell3.appendChild(btn1);
cell4.appendChild(btn2);
```

To make them functional, you need to add event handlers to them, something like this:

```
btn1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("button1 clicked");
});
btn2.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("button2 clicked");
});
```